# Does Xam.Plugin.Media Clean up the images it leaves in the app directory?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, portable-class-library

I can't seem to find an answer to this. If I am taking a photo on iOS and I supply a directory and name, what happens to the photo if I don't do anything with it.

I see the path leads /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/0727A3EF-A10B-416D-B9C2-6EDC4EC4AB42/Documents/WorkingImages/BaseImage_5.jpg

What happens to BaseImage_5.jpg? Am I responsible for deleting it?

Code:

```
var imageFile = await Current.TakePhotoAsync(new StoreCameraMediaOptions()
                {
                    Directory = "WorkingImages",
                    Name = "BaseImage",
                    CompressionQuality = 92,
                    PhotoSize = PhotoSize.Large
                });
```

Comment: AFAIK, the developer is responsible for any cleanup related to images stored in the app folders.

Comment: @Jason Going off of this, I installed the PCLStorage plugin to gain file access but it seems that the media plugin saves it directly to the documents while the PCLPlugin saves it to the document/../Library folder. Seems weird to me that the PCL storage points somewhere then the default documents and it makes it very hard to cleanup.